# Abrir modal bootstrap automaticamente ao carregar pagina

Tags: bootstrap, modal

Gente preciso que assim que a pagina carregar o modal do bootstrap abra na tela sem ser preciso clicar no botão, do jeito que estou fazendo ta sendo necessário clicar no botão para o modal abrir, segue o codigo:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary construcao" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exemplomodal">SITE EM CONSTRUÇÃO</button>



<div class="modal fade" id="exemplomodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
 labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">teste</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            teste

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#exemplomodal').modal('show');
})
</script>
```

Comment: Aparentemente tu está fazendo da maneira certa, estranho não estar funcionando, tenta o seguinte: $(window).load(function(){  $('#exemplomodal').modal('show');   }); caso não funcione, tenta um setTimeOut de 100ms

Comment: não funcionou, continua abrindo somente ao clique do botão, no inspecionar aparece que modal não é uma função, esse erro é comum ?

Comment: Então provavelmente seu erro está na declaração dos scripts, vou postar como uma resposta, um momento.

Comment: É só mandar dar um click no botao ao carregar a página e dar um .hide() no botão.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você está utilizando a maneira correta de abrir o modal do bootstrap:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#exemplomodal').modal('show');
})
```

Como o erro no console é

> .modal is not a function

Então provavelmente seu problema esta na ordem de declaração dos script's, declare eles na seguinte ordem:

```
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- chamada da função -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#exemplomodal').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

Isso acontece porque o bootstrap depende do jquery, ou seja, o jquery precisa necessariamente ser declarado antes.

Comment: o bootstrap esta depois do jquery... '-' todos os scripts estou chamando no head.. e o jquery vem primeiro.. depois o bootstrap.. porem continua dando esse erro de modal is not a function: segue..

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
    at home:41
    at handle (jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19)
    at jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19

Comment: realmente é algo com jquery

Comment: Hmm, tenta usar a versão mais recente do jquery, https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js

Comment: Usa esses dois, provavelmente vai funcionar: src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"

Comment: funcionou!!! realmente era a versão do jquery que tava antiga! muito obrigado amigo!